# Не работает std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, конструктор-копирования, std-forward

Нужно, что бы в зависимости от того, какая вызывается перегрузка `push_back` (lvalue или rvalue), вызывался соответствующий конструктор (копирования или перемещения):

```
struct tmpS {
    tmpS() {}
    tmpS(const tmpS& s) {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
    }
    tmpS(tmpS&& s) {
        std::cout << "move\n";
    }
};

template<typename Type>
void pass_to_construct(Type&& arg) { // универсальная ссылка
    tmpS t = std::forward<Type>(arg);
}

template<typename T>
struct v {
    v() {}
    void push_back(T&& value) { // вызовется эта перегрузка
        pass_to_construct(value);
    }

    void push_back(const T& value) {
        pass_to_construct(value);
    }

};

int main()
{
    v<tmpS> s;
    s.push_back(tmpS()); // rvalue
}
```

Код выше вызывает конструктор копирования (печатает copy). Почему не перемещения?

Comment: Правильно, у вас в `void push_back(T&& value)` вызывается вариант `tmpS(const tmpS& s)`. Чтобы вызвать `tmpS(tmpS&& s) ` необходимо сделать перемещение `pass_to_construct(::std::move(value));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
template<typename T>
struct v {
    v() {}
    void push_back(T&& value) { // вызовется эта перегрузка
        pass_to_construct(std::forward<T&&>(value));
    }
    void push_back(T& value) { // вызовется эта перегрузка
        pass_to_construct(value);
    }
};
```

Без этого в `pass_to_construct` всегда передается lvalue, каковым является аргумент функции.

Вот рабочий код: https://ideone.com/P4jR4w

Еще вариант -

```
void push_back(T&& value) { // вызовется эта перегрузка
    pass_to_construct(std::move(value));
}
void push_back(T& value) { // вызовется эта перегрузка
    pass_to_construct(value);
}
```

Какой вариант более правильный - не уверен... Ощущение, что в данном случае они оба сработают.

[P.S. По некотором раздумии - в данном случае нет универсальной ссылки, так что лучше применять `move`.]

Но в том, что в `pass_to_construct` в вашем варианте вы в обоих случаях передавали аргумент вызывающей функции, т.е. lvalue - это несомненно...

*"По-моему, так"... (с) Пух*

Comment: 2ой вариант точно рабочий

Comment: Мне второй больше нравится. `forward` обычно с forwarding-ссылками используют.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Как минимум он короче :). Но по некоторому раздумию я с вами согласен, в данном случае нет универсальной ссылки, так что лучше `move`.